# SqlException: On Delete Cascade not working ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I try to delete a user from the ASP.NETUsers table I get SqlException:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
> constraint "FK_Applications_AspNetUsers_UserID". The conflict occurred
> in database "JobGuide", table "dbo.Applications", column 'UserID'.

This problem is occurring because the User's Id is the Foreign key in another table, but "On delete cascade" is not working. For more details this is my model:

My extended Identity User:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

Application model (i.e. when a user applies for a job):

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Job model:

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

So up to here I created two **One to Many** relationships, AspNetUser one to many with Application and Job one to many with Application.

And this is my Fluent API mapping configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Application>()
        .HasKey(i => i.ApplicationID);

    builder.Entity<Application>()
           .HasOne<AppUser>(sc => sc.User)
           .WithMany(s => s.Applications)
           .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.UserID)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<Application>()
           .HasOne<Job>(sc => sc.Job)
           .WithMany(s => s.Applications)
           .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.JobID)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Delete method from controller:

```
    var userInfo = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
    if (userInfo == null) 
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _ = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(userInfo, userInfo.RoleName);
    _ = await userManager.DeleteAsync(userInfo);
    
    int rowsAffected = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Any idea why this error is not disappearing, is Fluent API good? or i need to type raw Sql to delete the Application with that User once and then the User? I have looked at almost all similar questions but none of them are working for me.

Comment: According to the model and the Fluent API configuration, I have created an Asp.net core 3.1 MVC application, when I using your delete code to delete an user, it will show a CS1503 error, after changing to `userManager.DeleteAsync(userInfo.result)`, the CS1503 error disappears, and the related data will delete success, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfCmS.png).Please check the Migrations files, have you ever enabled migrations after configure cascade deletes. And check the database, if there have null value or not.Besides, you could try to delete cascade items from DbContext.

Comment: I have tested my delete code and it works fine, but only when a user does not have an application in the Applications table, when a user has an application, exception appears. I tried your code but still fails. I checked the database and in the Applications table -> keys -> "FK_Applications_AspNetUsers_UserID" delete rule was "No action" i changed that to "Cascade" but still failing. 
I tried another method using Raw SQL Command look at this screenshot [link](https://i.imgur.com/nqHYXJf.png), this method is working fine but it seems to me that it is not an adequate method to delete an user?

Comment: Hi @sycamore55, It seems that the cascade delete is not configured in the application table, try to use SSMS to check it: open the SQL Server Object Explorer (or using Server Explorer), find the SQL Server Database, then right click the Applications table -> Script As -> CREATE To -> New Query Window, then check whether the table is configured Cascade delete, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvEG9.png).

Comment: @ZhiLv Oh you saved my life haha, I swear i checked it but apparently i did not save it, post this comment as answer and I will mark as solved, thanks.

Comment: Hi @sycamore55, Glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cascade delete is not configured in the application table, try to use [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) to check it:

Open the **SQL Server Object Explorer** (or using Server Explorer), find the SQL Server Database, then right click the **Applications** table -> **Script As** -> **CREATE To** -> **New Query Window**, then check whether the table is configured Cascade delete, check this screenshot:

[image]

To solve this issue, after configuration Cascade Delete using Fluent API mapping, please remember to enable migration and update the database:

```
  Add-Migration AddCascadeDelete
  Update-Database
```

Besides, you could also configure the Cascade Delete by executing the following SQL command (via SSMS):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Applications]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Applications_AspNetUsers_UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting it the other way around;

```
builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany<Application>(u => u.Applications)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

or use `.WillCascadeOnDelete()` on your code.

Comment: I have tried it to but it does not work, says:

**"NavigationBuilderCollection<AppUser, Application> does not contain a definition for 'Willcascadeondelete'**  :/

Comment: @sycamore55 oh, you're using entity framework core?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that.